# jQuery.fn.extend() - Cannot retrieve matched elements from methods of a object used to extend the $

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm stuck in the following situation. Hope you guys could help.

As you can see, i have extended jQuery main object by adding two methods. The problem is that the `testApp()` method's `this` keyword contains a reference to the matched set of elements (elements with class `p1`), but the function `appName.InitApp()` method's `this` keyword refer to the `appName` object (i know it's the default behavior). My question is that how could i get the matched set of element from the `appName.InitApp()` method.

```js
$.fn.extend({
    appName: (function () {
        "use strict";
        var obj = {};
        
        obj.InitApp = function () {
            console.log("appName");
            console.log(this);
            this.css("color", "red");
        };
        
        return obj;
    })(),
    
    testApp: function () {
        console.log("testApp");
        this.css("color", "red");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".p1").testApp();
    $(".p2").appName.InitApp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="p1">The first paragraph in body.</p>
<p class="p1">The second paragraph in body.</p>

<p class="p2">The third paragraph in body.</p>
<p class="p2">The fourth paragraph in body.</p>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you'd grab that 'this', as at the time you are creating the method to return for the InitApp variable, 'this' does not exist as the selected elements.

Comment: Which begs the question, why are you doing the IIFE there?

Comment: @Taplar `this` referes to the object `obj`.

Comment: I understand that.  You're asking how to make `this` refer to the selected elements, right?  But that doesn't exist at the time you create that method.

Comment: I would probably suggest moving `InitApp` from `$.fn` to just `$` making it a true top level method, and then pass in the selector to that method for which elements to select and work upon.  Because as it stands with your IIFE you're making a quasi-static method that doesn't play nicely with the $.fn namespace.

Comment: I know what kind of end result you're looking for, and i've seen it accomplished before, but it required fundamental changes to jquery's core method (it had to be overridden). I haven't been able to re-locate the code that does it, but I wouldn't suggest doing it anyway. Just drop the appName namespace and instead have it be a single method that accepts arguments. `$(selector).appName('initApp')` `$(selector).appName('testApp')` etc

Comment: Basically you would modify it such that every time a jquery object is created (pretty much every jquery filtering method, $(), .find, .filter, .children, .parents, .closest, etc) a new instance of your `appName` object would be created and attached to it with each of its methods bound to the current selection. that's quite inefficient, but it would *work*. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a satisfying answer for my problem.

The reason for my problem as i discovered, was that after extending jQuery prototype by appending an object, every newly created jQuery object is being referred by methods of the extending object, as its owner object (this). In my case, `appName` object is just an object that's been appended to jQuery object and its methods doesn't refer to the jQuery object. They refer to the `appName`. So i changed my code to pick up the jQuery object.

```js
$.fn.extend({
    appName: (function () {
        "use strict";
        var obj = {};
        var matchedElems = null;
        
        obj.InitApp = function () {
            if (matchedElems != undefined && 
            matchedElems != null) {
            console.log("appName");
            matchedElems.css("color", "red");
            }
        };
        
        return function () {
            matchedElems = this;
            return obj;
        };
    })(),
    
    testApp: function () {
        console.log("testApp");
        this.css("color", "red");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".p1").testApp();
    $(".p2").appName().InitApp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">The first paragraph in body.</p>
<p class="p1">The second paragraph in body.</p>

<p class="p2">The third paragraph in body.</p>
<p class="p2">The fourth paragraph in body.</p>
```